# A weird word appears with topic analysis in r

Tags: r

I have a paragraph:

> disgusting do at was horrific we have stayed please to at traveler photos ironic i did post those witnessed each every thing in pictures gave us fist free then moved us to rooms were any better we slept with clothes on entire there never once took off shoes to walk on carpet shower etc holes in wall stains on bedding curtains couch chair no working electric in  lamps cords nothing could be plugged in when we called  down to fix it so we no lighting except bathroom light tv toilets constantly plugged up shower drain.

That appears to be a little grammatically weird since I cleaned the paragraph. And I use the following code to extract work frequencies.

```
# create corpus
docs<-Corpus(VectorSource(example))

# stem document
docs<-tm_map(docs,stemDocument)

# create document-term matrix
dtm<-DocumentTermMatrix(docs)

# convert row names
rownames(dtm)<-"example"

# collapse matrix by summing over columns
freq<-colSums(as.matrix(dtm))

# length should be total number of terms
length(freq)

# create sort order (descending)
ord<-order(freq,decreasing=TRUE)

# list all terms in decreasing order of freq and write to disk
freq[ord]
```

Then the `freq[ord]` is:

[image: freq[ord]]

I am wondering why there is a word `ani` here, apparently, `ani` does not appear in my paragraph. Thanks.

Just figured the problem, the following code transfers `any` to `ani`, does anyone know how to avoid that?

```
docs<-tm_map(docs,stemDocument)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the word "any" after having being stemmed. The (in this case faulty) logic of the underlying function, `wordStem`, which uses  Dr. Martin Porter's stemming algorithm and the C libstemmer library generated by Snowball, changed the `y` to an `i`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other reasonable way to stem document? It seems that I do need to stem.

Comment: @AegeanT.Wu Sure, you can always stem it manually with `gsub` or `grep`. Alternately you could set go into in the underlying `wordStem` file and tweak it. I think you could also try toggleing "porter" and "porter2" to see if it changes it. OTOH you might just leave it the way it is now because as long as you understand what's going on it shouldn't be too problematic.

Comment: @AegeanT.Wu I almost forgot, you can also use `RWeka` for stemming